# Optimizing SQL query performance on a large dataset

Tags: postgresql

I have approx. 40 million rows of data in one table. This data includes latitudes and longitudes of multiple people. I often calculate things in a separate table and then insert it into original table but with this amount of data, it is taking ages to do so. How could I make this in a more efficient manner?

Mentioned columns:

"id": a unique id on the whole data (sorted by participant, date and time);
"participant": participant's id
"participant_file": an id of an original file in which the data was stored at the beginning (data of one participant sometimes stored in multiple files);
"id_file_row": a row number in the original file
E.g., to calculate delta time on a sorted data (sorted by date, and time; and partitioned by participant), I do the following:

```
-- create temporary table
CREATE TABLE temp_timestamp AS
SELECT id, participant, participant_file, id_file_row, date, time
FROM full_dataset
ORDER BY id ASC;

-- create timestamp from date and time
ALTER TABLE temp_timestamp ADD COLUMN datetime timestamp;
UPDATE temp_timestamp table1 SET datetime = table1.date + table1.time;

-- create temporary table to calculate delta time
CREATE TABLE temp_delta_time AS 
SELECT id, participant, participant_file, id_file_row, CAST((datetime - LAG(datetime, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY participant ORDER BY id)) AS time) AS delta_time
FROM temp_timestamp;

CREATE INDEX timestamp_idx ON indicate_2023.temp_delta_time(participant_file, id_file_row);

-- insert the sequence to the original dataset
ALTER TABLE full_dataset ADD COLUMN delta_time TIME;
UPDATE full_dataset table1
    SET delta_time = table2.delta_time
    FROM temp_delta_time table2
    WHERE table1.participant_file = table2.participant_file AND table1.id_file_row = table2.id_file_row;

-- remove temporary tables
DROP TABLE temp_timestamp;
DROP TABLE temp_delta_time;
```

Does creating the index timestamp_idx make sense in this use case?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Your insertion script doesn't do any insertions.  It would be better to have no commentary rather than misleading commentary.  But better yet to have accurate commentary.

Comment: I guess `full_dataset` is the big table. That's where the index might help.